# VisualStudio projects: modifications are not taken into consideration

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have (between others) 2 projects in my solution: one WinForm project, that defines a Form (say, MyFormProject), and other a UserControl (MyControlProject).

When I modify MyControlProject's code and launch the debug, I see that any modification is not taken into consideration. I need to clear the solution, rebuild, for make it work...

Additional info:
- I use in the UserControl the Dbi-Tech Components. Also, in the WinForm I use Infragistics components. Are both license files compatible, cause seems that both should user licenses.licx file?
- When I wrote a new method in the Control, I got a MissingMethod exception in runtime, however, the code compiled without any error... Then I removed the references, re-added them, and the exception in runtime didn't appear.

Should I now every time remove+add or clear+rebuild the solution for test my modifications?

Comment: Did you set MyFormProject to *depend* on the MyControlProject? (Right-click MyFormProject -> Project Dependancies...)

Comment: @adelphus: First time I see that option... But I see MyControlProject is checked in that list of dependancies... I didn't set it manually.

Comment: and also the build order is set first to the UserControl, and then to my form...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your projects have the dependencies set correctly in the project properties. Also with regards to removing and adding references, make sure that your references are not set to require a specific version. This can be checked by looking at the properties window while the reference is selected. If you require the specific version, your reference link breaks each time you rebuild the library and have to re add the reference.

Comment: dependencies are correctly set. I mean, exists, and the build order is correct: the form is UNDER the control. The reference's version in the form projet to the control's dll requires the 1.0.0.0 version, and exactly that version is set into the control's project.

Comment: What I was saying was to set require specific version to false. That way when you rebuild and the build number increments it won't break your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change any code in user control, you've to compile and add as reference.

Comment: what do u mean?Long back when I used user control, something like this I had to do. But that was not vs 2010.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but really, I ask a solution, you propose me do not search it? its inacceptable to re-add that reference each time I do a modification on the control... What if I make houndreds of modifications per day...

Comment: but did you have 2 third-party components, like I do?

Comment: I can understand what you are telling. It's really illogical to keep on re-adding the reference..No I didn't use any third party component. I made my own user control.

Comment: So... what it the cause that the code modification are not taken into consideration. Is first time that I have that problem. I had similar situations when, instead referencing the dll projet, I referenced the built stand alone .dll. But now I really reference the dll project, not just the dll

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have it set so that dependent projects are rebuilt: In the options, Projects and Solution -> Build and Run, see that "Only build startup projects..." is unchecked, and "On Run, when projects are out of date" is set to "Prompt" or "Always build".